# snapshot.hasData is true but the snapshot.data.length is null, Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mobile, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm calling an API  from a component that returns some data, but the problem is `snapshot.hasData` is `true` but the `snapshot.data.length` is `0`. Am I parsing the data wrong(again)? The code:

API call service component:

```
Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    final response = await APIRequest(Method.GET, '/users');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      print('this is the response body: ' + response.body); // it returns data completely
      List<User> users = [];
      body.map((e) {
        User user = User.fromJson(e);
        users.add(user);
      });
      return users;
    } else {
      print('Error occurred! Data is not fetched!');
    }
  }
```

The user list component:

```
Future<List<User>> _getUserList() async {
    var _userData = await APIcalls.instance.getUsers();
    return _userData;
  }

FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
                    future: _getUserList(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print(snapshot.hasData.toString()); // returns true
                        print(snapshot.data.length); // returns 0
                        return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print(snapshot.data.length);

                            return Text(snapshot.data[index].userId);
                          },
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }
                      return Container();
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: In your `getUsers` method, you returned `posts`...Where is it coming from?

Comment: typo, fixed it in the asked question

Comment: add  the JSON response that you are getting from API to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 List<User> users = List.from(body).map((e) => User.fromJson(Map.from(e))).toList();
 return users;
```

Comment: It works mate, thanks a lot! If you don't mind, care to explain? Why `Map` and should I always use it in the API calls when parsing `JSON` data? I'm trying to learn the best way possible when parsing JSON data, it's not like JS where you just call the API and that's that, here in Dart/Flutter thing are done differently...

Comment: The decoded response.body (i.e `jsonDecode(response.body))` returns an object of `_InternalLinkedHashMap` and `fromJson` requires an object `Map`. So you have to convert it.